# Serious applications of Colouring proofs

Tags: problem-solving

Are there any research-level applications of proofs by colouring?

This is the kind of proof you use to show that you can't cover a mutilated chessboard with 31 dominoes. Afaik, this technique chiefly finds a market in IMO preparation classes; see  [Arthur Engel's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191) or  [this handout](http://mei.org.uk/files/pdf/09conference/2009HandoutF9.pdf) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can formally distinguish "proofs by coloring" from "parity arguments" or more generally arguments that use some mapping into a finite domain, say be reducing mod m. Coloring is just a visually appealing way of looking at such an argument. Needless to say, proofs by parity arguments or other mappings into a finite set are very common; this is a fundamental tool in combinatorics and number theory.

Answer (score 4):

[Sperner's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma) has [several applications](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jch1/research/old/sperner.pdf), including the effective computation of fixed points and a constructive proof of the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed_point_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

[Conway's Soldiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Soldiers) is a proof-by-coloring with an infinity of colors.

Comment: This is nice.  I think the link might not be exactly what you meant it to be, though?

Comment: I cut'n'pasted but the last part of the URL didn't become part of the link. I'm hoping someone who knows more about these things than I do (and that's setting the bar pretty low) will come along and fix the link.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Soldiers

Comment: you can use this syntax for links: `[link](url)`, as in [Conway's Soldiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Soldiers).

Answer (score 1):

There is a vertex coloring argument that is used in Steve Fisk's elegant proof of the Chvatal-Klee-Art Gallery Theorem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem  The coloring argument can be extended to handle the case where the art gallery is a rectilinear (orthogonal) polygon.